# Using /proc/<pid>, how can I identify a network port number's application?

Tags: sockets, tcp, port, pid, proc

I'm trying to identify what application is running on port 56474 without having root access.  I know the application was started by me.

Example:

```
netstat -tunap

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:56474           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I've tried using /proc/pid scripts to walk all  using grep on ls -l /proc/pid/fd results.  Here is my attempt.  NOTE: Not sure if I was heading the right direction

```
for I in `find /proc/*/fd -exec ls -l {} \; 2>/dev/null | awk -F"->|:" '/socket/ {print $4}' | sort -u | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g'`; do grep $I /proc/*/net/tcp; done
```

I had no success.  Not sure if there is a way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NOTE: Added another answers as `lsof` was not satisfactory.

This should work:

```
#! /bin/bash
port=56474
hex_port=$(echo "obase=16; $port" | bc )

inode=$(cat /proc/net/tcp | grep ":$hex_port" | awk '{print $10}')

for i in $(ps axo pid); do
        ls -l /proc/$i/fd 2> /dev/null | grep -q ":\[$inode\]" &&  echo $i
done
```

Explanation:

Once we have the port number converted to Hexadecimal, we can get the inode number from /proc/net/tcp (10th field), then we loop through /proc/pids/fd and find a symlink pointing to the inode.

Comment: Nice!  It works!  I ran it it give me a the pid of the application's name.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This doesn't work on all systems without root access, because sometimes you're not allowed to access `/proc/<PID>/fd`. PS Sorry, I've missed the "I know the application was started by me" sentence, so the poster has access to his own `/proc/<PID>/fd`.

Comment: The usual [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) fix: `awk ":$hex_port { print \$10 }" /proc/net/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the application was started by you then you can use `lsof`:

`/usr/sbin/lsof -nP | grep :56474 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: Thanks, however, I would need to use the /proc/* solution.  I'm currently looking for a book that describes each "file" in /proc to see if it can be achieved.

Comment: It can, just added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique to resolve pids and ports of all running apps without root:

1.) Get the **pids** of running apps. Either use the **ActivityManager** or parse a **ps** console output.

2.) iterate through /proc/$pid/net/status files and get the matching **uid** for a **pid**.

```
    cat /proc/*pid*/net/status | grep Uid:
```

3.) Call and parse the output of **tcp**, **tcp6**,**udp**, **udp6** files to match **ports** and **uids**:

```
    cat /proc/net/tcp 
    ...
```

4.) match the **uids** of both matchings, get a **port-to-pid** map without su access.

Cheers,

goethe

Comment: /edit: uid could also be aquired by AcktivityManager.